# Experience (of) creating software

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to phrase the following sentence for my portfolio: "I'm a C#/Js/Python developer with 10+ years of experience creating software at corporations and cutting-edge startups". I'm confused whether it's necessary to put of between experience and creating. Two of close to each other seem to sound a little off, so may be if of is necessary, it would be better to rephrase it to sound more native-like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No preposition is necessary in the following:

> I'm a C#/Js/Python developer with 10+ years of **experience creating** software at corporations and cutting-edge startups.

*Experience in (gerund)* is a common usage in English. [In this list](https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/noun_prep_gerund_list.htm) of common combinations of nouns followed by prepositions and gerunds, both *experience in* and *experience* without a preposition are acceptable:

> She has a great deal of **experience in introducing** new products to international markets.
>
> With the noun "experience," sometimes a gerund is added without the preposition "in." "**Experience introducing** new products" would also be acceptable.

As an illustration, [look at these book blurbs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ten%20years%20of%20experience%20creating%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj085uptNfgAhXMmeAKHXQLB3sQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1920&bih=966) which feature the exact phrase "ten years of experience creating ..."